# change element border-color on blur

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change my text box's border color on blur

```
var checking = document.getElementById("checking");
function checkTextField() {
       document.getElementById("checking").style.border = "2px solid green";
}

function blurEventFunc() {
      if (document.getElementById("checking") === ''){
        document.getElementById("checking").style.border = "2px solid red";
    } else {
       document.getElementById("checking").style.border = "2px solid green";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
your question should be as clear as possible so others will help you with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check if the value is empty, not the element its self.
also inside the blur function, you can refer to the element using the `this` keyword

```js
function blurEventFunc() {
      if (this.value === ''){
        this.style.border = "2px solid red";
    } else {
       this.style.border = "2px solid green";
    }
}

document.getElementById("checking").addEventListener('blur', blurEventFunc);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="checking" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much @NitsanBaleli

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the value instead of the whole element

```
if (document.getElementById("checking").value === '')
```